# Can I get an interactive plot in ggplot2 or rCharts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, interactive, rcharts, polychart

```
structure(list(Date = c("2013-11-17", "2013-11-18", "2013-11-19", 
"2013-11-20", "2013-11-21", "2013-11-22", "2013-11-23", "2013-11-25", 
"2013-11-26", "2013-11-27", "2013-11-28", "2013-11-29", "2013-11-30", 
"2013-12-02", "2013-12-03", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-05", "2013-12-06", 
"2013-12-07", "2013-12-09", "2013-12-10", "2013-12-11", "2013-12-12", 
"2013-12-13", "2013-12-14", "2013-12-16", "2013-12-17", "2013-11-17", 
"2013-11-18", "2013-11-19", "2013-11-20", "2013-11-21", "2013-11-22", 
"2013-11-23", "2013-11-25", "2013-11-26", "2013-11-27", "2013-11-28", 
"2013-11-29", "2013-11-30", "2013-12-01", "2013-12-02", "2013-12-03", 
"2013-12-04", "2013-12-05", "2013-12-06", "2013-12-07", "2013-12-09", 
"2013-12-10", "2013-12-11", "2013-12-12", "2013-12-13", "2013-12-14", 
"2013-12-16", "2013-12-17"), Catagory = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("build", "client"), class = "factor"), 
    User_Name = c(1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
    4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
    6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L), 
    type = c("obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", 
    "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", 
    "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", 
    "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj1", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", 
    "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", 
    "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", 
    "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", "obj2", 
    "obj2")), .Names = c("Date", "Catagory", "User_Name", "type"
), row.names = c(NA, 55L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the below code to generate a path plotting to compare two different variables over time.

```
library(rCharts)

econ <- transform(dat, Date = as.character(Date))
attach(econ)
pic<-rPlot(x="Date",y=c("User_Name"),color="type",data=econ,type="line")
```

Even though the plot is supposed to be interactive there is no sign of it i.e. like tootip feature & all. I don't know how to add interactivity in ggplot2 that's why I planned to use rCharts for simple interactivity. can anyone tell me how to do this in rCharts and in ggplot2 if at all possible. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no interactivity with ggplot2 ( even it is the future of ggplot2). With `rPlot` you can get interactivity (tooltip feature) if you use **point** as a **geom** or you add a **point layer**. For example:

```
library(rCharts)
econ <- transform(dat, Date = as.character(Date))
attach(econ)
pic <- rPlot(User_Name~Date,color="type",data=econ,type="line") 
pic$layer(x = "Date", y = "User_Name", 
           data = econ, type = 'point', size = list(const = 3))
pic
```

Comment: ok adding a layer tooltip is working. but in a certain point the value of Date, I mean in tooltip condition, is somewhat unwanted. can u tell how to fix this?

Comment: i mean in the generated plot if u use the tooltip feature to see the current value of that point by pointing ur mouse over the point in the plot u will notice the value of "Date" is not in proper format.